# Can't compile core source project with Corda V3

Tags: corda

After I git fetch and checkout release-V3.2.1847. I met some errors of test codes.

Code refer here:
**subFlow(IdentitySyncFlow.Send(session, tx))**

the IDEA report error
**"Canno access class 'net.corda.core.flows.FlowSession'. Check your module classpath for missing or confliction dependencies"**

Below list codes have same errors:

```
confidential-identities/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/confidential/IdentitySyncFlowTests.kt
    finance/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/finance/contracts/asset/DummyFungibleContract.kt
    node/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/node/services/identity/PersistentIdentityServiceTests.kt
    tools/demobench/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/demobench/model/NodeConfigTest.kt
```

Please help,  Thank you Team.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by deleting and redownloading the `Corda` repository.